# prevent early fire of Task.Delay

Tags: c#, task, delay

I learned that `Task.Delay` may complete a little earlier as described in documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8

> This method depends on the system clock. This means that the time delay will approximately equal the resolution of the system clock if the delay argument is less than the resolution of the system clock, which is approximately 15 milliseconds on Windows systems.

How do I prevent it from finishing even 1 ms earlier?
Say I need following code:

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

to continue after at least 1000 ms but not earlier.

Best code I am able to come up with that doesn't continue earlier than after 1000 ms is:

```
await Task.Delay(1000+16);
```

but this approach looks weird and dirty.

Comment: windows is not a real-time operating system.

Comment: Record when you started the delay (using a high-precision timer), look at when you finished the delay, and delay for a bit longer if necessary?

Comment: Why do you want such precision in the first place? Unless you process audio/video in real time, it's pointless. Task.Delay *can't* offer better precision than the OS itself - there are a *lot* of layers below it that make it impossible to even offer identical precision, eg the GC can run at any time. *Tasks* resume when a thread becomes available.. The OS itself only offers such precision for C/C++ code using the multimedia scheduler

Comment: If you want to control some kind of animation, the solution is to let the OS do it for you, not try to do it yourself. Games use DirectX since 19995 to let the OS play audio/video without hickups. WPF already offers animation, timelines etc.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos for high frequency trading software. Waiting extra 16 ms is not an big deal but with await Task.Delay(1000+16) it may unnecessarily skip several system clock events in range of 1000-1015 ms. No super precision is necessary. I would just like to have something that doesn't continue earlier than specified.